# Logging from msbuild Custom Task using Console class

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I'm trying to convert an existing command line tool into msbuild custom task.
This tool logs messages and errors using the System.Console class.
I've added to the tool's assembly a class that inherits from Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Task and calls the tool main function, and the custom tool works fine - but no messages/errors are displayed (on the Visual Studio output window).

I would like to avoid changing the original tool's code (otherwise I could change every "Console.Error.WriteLine" to "Log.LogError").
I thought of changing the stdout and stderr streams of console by calling Console.SetOut and SetError before calling the tool's main function. For that, I would need to implement a class that inherits from TextWriter.

So my questions are:

1. Why System.Console writes aren't
   automatically sent to Log of
   BuildSystem?
2. Is inheriting from TextWriter and setting the streams of Console - a good
   solution for this problem?
3. Perhaps someone already did this
   work and wrote a TextWriter
   implementation for sending
   output/error to the msbuild log?
4. If not, where can I find some
   reference code that gives an example
   of a class that implements
   TextWriter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Class TaskLogger
Inherits TextWriter

Public Enum TaskLoggerType
    out
    err
End Enum

Private m_logger As TaskLoggingHelper
Private m_logger_type As TaskLoggerType

Sub New(ByRef logger As TaskLoggingHelper, ByVal type As TaskLoggerType)
    m_logger = logger
    m_logger_type = type
End Sub

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Encoding As System.Text.Encoding
    Get
        Return System.Text.Encoding.Default
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides Sub WriteLine(ByVal value As String)
    Select Case m_logger_type
        Case TaskLoggerType.out
            m_logger.LogMessage(value)
        Case TaskLoggerType.err
            m_logger.LogError(value)
    End Select
End Sub
End Class
```

...

```
Public Overrides Function Execute() As Boolean
    Dim oldOut As TextWriter = Console.Out
    Dim oldErr As TextWriter = Console.Error
    Dim newOut As TextWriter = New TaskLogger(Log, TaskLogger.TaskLoggerType.out)
    Dim newErr As TextWriter = New TaskLogger(Log, TaskLogger.TaskLoggerType.err)
    Console.SetOut(newOut)
    Console.SetError(newErr)
    Dim result As Boolean = Run(...)
    Console.SetOut(oldOut)
    Console.SetOut(oldErr)
    Return result
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to have a wrapper task, inheriting from ToolTask, which just invokes this external tool, stdout/stderr messages would get logged correctly. You could even override LogEventsFromTextOutput and correctly match and log errors and warnings, which would show up in VS. Eg. [LC.cs](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/LC.cs)

Comment: When you say "invokes this external tool" do you mean by starting a new process? I could have used Exec task for that instead of wrapping the tool.   My goal is to call the tool's main function many times efficiently from msbuild without starting a new process every time.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. New process would indeed be expensive. I would suggest changing the Console.Write* calls to Log calls, gives you better control over errors/warnings/messages. Eg, you could log debug messages from your tool with MessageImportance.Low, which wouldn't pollute regular output, but be useful when trying to debug an error. Also, changing Console's Out/Err might not play well with other things that might depend on it, being executed in parallel.

Comment: In this case, as I mentioned in the quesion, I would like to avoid changing the original tool's code. But I wonder if changing the Console's Out/Err could affect other things running in parallel... Are you sure about this? Wouldn't it affect only the same assembly from which I make the change?

Comment: AFAICS, it should affect the appdomain in which it is executing.